# What is preventing function from being called infinitely?

Tags: javascript, recursion, dom, callback, traversal

The functions purpose is to traverse the DOM passing through a callback function on each child element. If traverseDom calls itself and starts the entire function over, I would expect that element = element.nextElementSibling would never be reached. Even though we would eventually hit the last child in the node tree, I would assume that nothing is stopping the function from calling itself infinitely trying to find additional children even after we’ve reached the last child.

```js
function traverseDom(element, callback) {
  callback(element);
  element = element.firstElementChild;

  while (element) {
    traverseDom(element, callback);
    element = element.nextElementSibling;
  }
}
const subTree = document.getElementById("subTree");
traverseDom(subTree, function(element) {
  console.assert(element !== null, element.nodeName);
});
```

```html
<div id="subTree">
  <form>
    <input type="text" />
  </form>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <span>Span</span>
</div>
```

I expected this to run infinitely and never reach the sibling element declaration.

Comment: Don't use curly quotes in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the deepest nested element, `element.firstElementChild` will be `null`, and so after assigning that to `element`, the following condition will not be true:

```
while(element) {
```

...and so the loop is not entered at all. There is no further recursion at that point, the function returns, and backtracking can happen. The function executing at the previous level of recursion may still loop further, but eventually there will always be a deepest level where the loop does not execute. These represent the leaves in the depth-first traversal tree.

### Variable Scope

There is also another aspect which may lead to confusion: the variable `element` is *local* to the current function execution context: a change in its value (due to an assignment), will not affect the variable with the same name in the *calling* function.

To clarify this, you could also rewrite the code to use a different variable name to which you will assign the child nodes:

```js
function traverseDom(element, callback) {
  callback(element);
  var child = element.firstElementChild;

  while (child) {
    traverseDom(child, callback);
    child = child.nextElementSibling;
  }
}
const subTree = document.getElementById("subTree");
traverseDom(subTree, function(element) {
  console.assert(element !== null, element.nodeName);
});
```

```html
<div id="subTree">
  <form>
    <input type="text" />
  </form>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <span>Span</span>
</div>
```

This code will produce the same result; it uses the same logic, except that it does not assign a new value to `element`, but uses a different variable for that new value (the first child). But notice that when the function is called recursively, the value of `child` becomes the value of the parameter-variable `element`.

Comment: Isn’t element = element.nextElementSibling part of the while loop? If element is no longer true for the while condition, then wouldn’t we not be able to append element.nextElementSibling because our while loop wouldn’t execute?

Comment: Maybe your confusion as about the local scope that `element` has. When I write that *before* the loop `element` becomes `null`, then that does *not* affect the value that `element` has in the *calling* function, because that is a *different* variable that is not affected by anything that happens during the recursive call.

Answer (score 1):

Generators enable you to do this in a more convenient way -

```js
function* traverseDom (elem) {
  yield elem
  for (const child of elem.children)
    yield* traverseDom(child)
}

const subTree =
  document.getElementById("subTree")

for (const elem of traverseDom(subTree))
  console.log(elem, elem.nodeName)
  
for (const elem of traverseDom(subTree))
  console.assert(elem !== null, elem.nodeName)
```

```html
<div id="subTree">
  <form>
    <input type="text" />
  </form>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <span>Span</span>
</div>
```

If you prefer the higher-order function, that is possible as well -

```js
function traverseDom (f, elem) {
  f(elem)
  for (const child of elem.children)
    traverseDom(f, child)
}

const subTree =
  document.getElementById("subTree")

traverseDom
  ( elem => console.log(elem, elem.nodeName)
  , subTree
  )
  
traverseDom
  ( elem => console.assert(elem !== null, elem.nodeName)
  , subTree
  )
```

```html
<div id="subTree">
  <form>
    <input type="text" />
  </form>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <span>Span</span>
</div>
```